# Control.InvokeRequired is false in a Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, begininvoke

I do have a Form which is registered on an update event. There I check if invoke is required and process the update either directly or via BeginInvoke:

```
protected void CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { ProcessCollectionChanged(e); }));
        return;
    }
    ProcessCollectionChanged(e);
}
```

BUT: this does not always work! I know the details - the handle is created, i did even check the internal code and all is sane, from the watch window:

```
    System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.GetCurrentThreadId() 3540    int
    System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(new System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef(this, Handle), out _); 3540    int
    InvokeRequired  false   bool
    IsHandleCreated true    bool
```

and of course my call stack of proof:

```
MyApp.Forms.dll!MyApp.Forms.TreeViews.BaseDataObjectTreeList.CollectionChanged(object sender = {MyApp.Client.DataStore}, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e = {System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs}) Line 809    C#
MyApp.DataProvider.dll!MyApp.DataProvider.DataCache<MyApp.DataObject>.RaiseCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs eventArgs = {System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs}) Line 465    C#
MyApp.Client.dll!MyApp.Client.DataCache<MyApp.DataObject>.RaiseCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs eventArgs = {System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs}) Line 353    C#
MyApp.DataProvider.dll!MyApp.DataProvider.DataCache<MyApp.DataObject>.DataObjects_CollectionChanged(object sender = {My.Utils.ObservableDictionary<string, MyApp.DataObject>}, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e = {System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs}) Line 127  C#
My.Utils.dll!My.Utils.ObservableDictionary<string, MyApp.DataObject>.OnCollectionChanged(bool firePropertyChanged = false, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction action = Remove, System.Collections.IList changedItems = {System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, MyApp.DataObject>[1]}) Line 618   C#
My.Utils.dll!My.Utils.ObservableDictionary<string, MyApp.DataObject>.EndUpdate.AnonymousMethod__5() Line 517    C#
My.Utils.dll!My.Utils.ObservableDictionary<string, MyApp.DataObject>.EndUpdate() Line 534   C#
My.Utils.dll!My.Utils.ObservableDictionary<string, MyApp.DataObject>.UpdateBatch.Dispose() Line 663 C#
MyApp.DataProvider.dll!MyApp.DataProvider.DataCache<MyApp.DataObject>.UpdateCache(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> keys = {string[1]}, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction action = Remove) Line 700 C#
MyApp.Client.dll!MyApp.Client.DataCache<MyApp.DataObject>.UpdateCache(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> keys = {string[1]}, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction action = Remove) Line 339 C#
MyApp.Client.dll!MyApp.Client.DataStore.UpdateCache(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> keys = {string[1]}, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction action = Remove) Line 44    C#
MyApp.Client.dll!MyApp.Client.DataCache<MyApp.DataObject>.Update.AnonymousMethod__0() Line 683  C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot = Id = 230, Status = Running, Method = "Void <Update>b__0()")   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    Unknown
```

I can reproduce it when I close my dialog more or less about the same time an update occurs. The dialog is already hidden, the update is received on an other thread. The task finds no need to BeginInvoke and Update the controls. Meanwhile the main thread goes on and disposes the form. Now an exception is raised in the task (which is magically swallowed to nowhere).

Comment: I don't understand your "call stack of proof".  Because `ProcessCollectionChanged` is not on your stack.  Can you explain what you mean by _"this does not always work"_ and what you are experiencing that convinces you that's true?

Comment: What does *Control.BeginInvoke is false in a Task* mean? Do you mean that `InvokeRequired` is false (btw, you don't need to check `InvokeRequired` if you're using `BeginInvoke()`)? You need to provide means to cancel a Task if the Form closes, e.g., passing a `CancellationToken` and calling `[CancellationTokenSource].Cancel()`

Comment: @Wyck I tried to simplify the code and missed to delete the "DataObject_" prefix. What convinces me that it is not working is: I get InvokeRequired == false but I am clearly not on the main thread but in a ThreadPoolThread

Comment: @toATwork how do you know that? Did you invoke the asynchronous method using `Task.Run()`? Or with a continuation? Or by some other method that queues it for execution on the `ThreadPool`?

Comment: @Jimi By 'Task' I mean the  'System.Threading.Thread.Task' (as seen in the call stack). I can't change anything here because the update is received via WCF and this is the way they are handling updated - handle it in a ThreadPool Thread. I don't want to cancel the task. I want the InvokeRequired to work.

Comment: @PatrickTucci No, I did not invoke anything. It is a WCF Update. Those are handled async. I can see clearly in the debug Window that it is not the main thread, as the main thread is busy closing the form.

Comment: I know what is a Task, it's the title of your question that states *Control.BeginInvoke is false*, while you're referring to `InvokeRequired`. You don't need to check `InvokeRequired` if you're using `BeginInvoke()`, you need it if you call `Invoke()`. The method call, whether `InvokeRequired` is true or false doesn't change. It would imply a different behavior if you called back `CollectionChanged` in case `InvokeRequired = true`. But you don't. The problem here appears to be that your Task is not canceled if the Form closes.

Comment: Is the form in the process of going away while this ThreadPool worker thread tries to do something with it?  It's like when the son returns home from college saying "I've just got to get a few things from my room", but mom says, "Son, didn't you hear? We sold the house."  Your task is calling CollectionChanged on a form that is closed (or soon to be closed.)

Comment: @Jimi Thank you! Happend because I am looking at this for too long now. I do not want to always BeginInvoke the ProcessUpdate. If it is caused by me, then I want to do it in sync.

Comment: @Wyck Yes, the form is closed but not yet disposed and the Handle is perfectly valid. And according to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired?view=netcore-3.1) it should work: 'Control.InvokeRequired Property: true if the control's Handle was created on a different thread than the calling thread (indicating that you must make calls to the control through an invoke method); otherwise, false.'